# HTML: Bootstrap validating form (Confirming the input value is equal to a string)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building some administrator features and I pretty much don't understand JavaScript enough to do the validation for my form. So here I got the form:

[image]

Now I need to make sure that the user input is equal to the text above which is generated by my engine. In this case it's **delete ticket-74516ce5-7629-45c0-aca2-e48493609d0d**

Here's my code for generating the Close Ticket Window:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Close Ticket
                    </div>
                </h5>

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <span class="text-center text-dark p-3 border-bottom shadow-sm" style="background-color: #ffe88a;font-size: 14px;">Unexpected bad things will happen if you don’t read this!</span>
            <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #fafafa;font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;">
                <p>
                    <span class="font-weight-bold text-dark">Warning: This action cannot be undone.</span>
                    <br>
                <p>This will permanently delete the <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ticket.issuer_topic}}/{{ticket.issuer_first_name}}</span> ticket .</p>
                    Please type: <span id="ticket_del_text" name="ticket_del_text" class="font-weight-bold text-dark">delete ticket-{{ticket.public_id}}</span> to confirm.
                </p>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" required minlength="32" maxlength="80">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete Ticket </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure that I should use `onClick` Html given parameter on Delete Ticket button and then check the value of the "Delete Confirmation Text" and the user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute in your input.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Default" required pattern={{ticket.public_id}}>
```

To add a custom validation message, add this to your input

```
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('my custom error message here')"
oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"
```

Comment: This seem to work! Any way how can I change the message if it doesn't match the format?

Comment: @DzITC, note that the user can inspect your page and delete the pattern attribute oor even modifie it

Comment: @SaymoinSam yes,  you're right, I have back-end for that. But also If I would use onclick javascript function, the user also can remove the attribute.

Comment: Ok  since you have Backend validation, it should be fine

Comment: @SaymoinSam Maybe there's any way of doing something like this ? If user enters correct pattern the button should change it's status from disabled to normal?

Comment: @DzITC in order to toggle the button status, you'd have to keep track of the inputs validation. this can be achieved using an onchange event listener, for example.